# Is dhtmlx and i18next compatible?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, multilingual, dhtmlx, i18next

I am trying to use [i18next](http://i18next.com/) together with [dhtmlx](http://dhtmlx.com/) framework. I can include the library and get the translations to work, but when I include the i18next javascript library my layout is failing.

Have anyone tried those libraries together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the examples from i18next they wrote the include like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[PATH]/i18next.js" />
```

It worked when I changed it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[PATH]/i18next.js"></script>
```

I don´t know what the difference is, please comment if you know.